# Using loop count to modify variable name in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to have review.avg_answer2, review.avg_answer3, etc outputted by the following loop:

```
  <% @count = 1 %>
  <% 10.times do |x| %>
    <td><%= link_to review.avg_answer1.to_i, "#" %></td>
    <% @count += 1 %>
  <% end %>
```

I know there is a simple answer, but it's not hitting me.

I tried `"review.avg_answer#{@count}.to_i"` but of course it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work ?

```
review.send("avg_answer#{@count}").to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you case.. 
`10.times.each {|x| review.send("avg_answer#{x}")} OR`10.times.each {|x| review.send(:"avg_answer#{x}")}`

If you envision to pass Params to your method then you can vary it by:
`10.times.each {|x| review.send("avg_answer#{x}",params1,params2)}`
 OR `10.times.each {|x| review.send(:"avg_answer#{x}",params1,params2)}`